# Xamarin Build Failure with CocosSharp Portable Game Template

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, cocossharp

So I'm not really sure where to go on this one. I resolved all the dependency issues I had when I loaded the CocosSharp Portable template but the Android Project in the solution just refuses to build.

> > C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> >     Studio\2019\Preview\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2303,3):
> >     error XA4209: Failed to create JavaTypeInfo for class:
> >     Android.Support.V4.View.Accessibility.AccessibilityManagerCompat/IAccessibilityStateChangeListenerImplementor
> >     due to System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of
> >     the path 'C:\Users\Anthony\Source\Repos\CocosSharp Test Game
> >     Portable\CocosSharp Test Game Portable\CocosSharp Test Game
> >     Portable.Droid\obj\Debug\81\android\src\mono\android\support\v4\view\accessibility\AccessibilityManagerCompat_AccessibilityStateChangeListenerImplementor.java'.

I've seen a number of other questions that include a null reference exception when attempting to build this but not one that has could not find part of path.

**What I've tried:**

- Clean and rebuild the entire solution
- Clean and rebuild just the android project
- Manually clean and build each individual project
- Manually delete each project bin and obj folder and rebuild solution
- Generating an android manifest in the android project properties page
- Adding the `BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE` permission in the android manifest

Comment: Do you used Visual Studio 2019? If so, you can try to run your project the visual studio 2017, VS 2019 is preview, it may cause some issues.

Comment: Do you fixed this issue ? I am having the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. The path is too long. Too solve this issue I changed the location of my solution folder to a location with a shorter path. That's it. Close the solution, move the folder and reopen the solution.